# Bash changing a series of senteces and making them into single line ones

Tags: string, bash, file, sed, tr

What i would like to do, is load from a text file, containing series of sentences and creating an array containing each sentence as a separate index with some possible grep conditions, such as contains a string.
Here's what i got. The reason it's in array is because I would like it to count later the number of lines, but that I can do with simple for cycle if its in array, so i would like to keep it that way

```
#!/bin/bash
location=$(pwd)
file="${location}/text"
cat $file

string=$(cat $file |sed 's/./.*/g' | tr '*' '\n' |sed 's/?/?*/g' | tr '*' '\n' |sed 's/!/!*/g' | tr '*' '\n')
```

int this part i opened a file , and based on what i understand i replaced a . with .* and than replaced * with \n and did the same with ?!. So now i should have a string containing each sentence separated with a new line

```
echo $string

array=( $($string | grep "hello" | grep "!") )

echo $array
```

now it should put the string into array, with condition that there is a word hello and is a command sentence. But the problem is:

```
echo $string
otuput : . . . . . . . . . . . . etc...
```

also the line where a create an array is saying that .: .: is a directory... all code not separated below

```
#!/bin/bash
location=$(pwd)
file="${location}/text"
cat $file

string=$(cat $file |sed 's/./.*/g' | tr '*' '\n' |sed 's/?/?*/g' | tr '*' '\n' |sed 's/!/!*/g' | tr '*' '\n')

echo $string

array=( $($string | grep "hello" | grep "!") )

echo $array
```

example text

```
Text text hello! hello? text text.
text text. text hello! text?
hello! text text.
```

expected outputs:

```
echo $string : 
Text text hello!
 hello?
 text text.
text text.
 text hello!
 text?
hello!
 text text.
```

basically one sentence per line (yes sometimes whitespace at the beggining but it doesnt matter), since the string=$(cat $file |sed 's/./.*/g' | tr '*' '\n' |sed 's/?/?*/g' | tr '*' '\n' |sed 's/!/!*/g' | tr '*' '\n') is supposed to make it so
but current output for echo $string :

```
Text text hello! hello? text text. text text. text hello! text? hello! text text.
```

as for echo $array

```
basically the same as $string but each line as separate index in array
```

but current output looks the same as $string, prints it as one string rather than each sentence in new line

Please keep it within simple level, i just stared bash and created this script to learn and have fun, I know there are some incredible people using it, but from what I've seen it can get relay crazy fast :)

Comment: In sed, `.` on left side of `s///` matches **any** character. Use `\.` or `[.]`. For efficiency, you don't need to invoke sed and tr multiple times: sed already includes a `y` operator, and can accept multiple actions with either `;` or `-e`

Comment: i did add the \ as you suggested, is seems to fix the echo problem of $string :). But does echo ignore the \n command? becaouse it prints it out one after each other..

Comment: also the line with array=( $($string | grep "hello" | grep "!") ) says string :command not found ? but its just the content of string right? why would i search for command?

Comment: Read about "parameter expansion" and "word splitting".  You need to use double-quotes otherwise whitespace in variables will get modified.

Comment: `$( x )` says execute command `x`. `$( $x )` says execute the command that results from expanding `$x`

Comment: well tried both  array=( $($string | grep "hello" | grep "!") )   and   array=( $(string | grep "hello" | grep "!") ) none of them worked, tried doing echo $string | grep "hello" | grep "!"  but even that doesnt work, so there is probably some problem with the string i have or some way im handling it

Comment: please update the question to show a) the output from each of the `echo` calls (and note whether this is the correct/expected output for eacho `echo` call) and b) the expected output corresponding to the 3-line *'example text'* you've provided

Comment: What should the result be for presented text? How is a "sentence" defined? `array=( $(string | ` you have to do `array=( $( echo "$string" | grep ...) )` . There's an `echo`. And there are `"` quotes. Check your script with shellcheck - it will help you.

Comment: edited the outputs and how i think it should look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `echo $string` - please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [why-is-printf-better-than-echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ string=$(sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\n/g' file)
$ printf '%s\n' "$string"
Text text hello!
hello?
text text.
text text.
text hello!
text?
hello!
text text.
```

```
$ readarray -t -d$'\n' array < <(sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\n/g' file)
$ printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
Text text hello!
hello?
text text.
text text.
text hello!
text?
hello!
text text.
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="Text text hello!" [1]="hello?" [2]="text text." [3]="text text." [4]="text hello!" [5]="text?" [6]="hello!" [7]="text text.")
```

```
$ string=$(sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\n/g' file | grep 'hello!')
$ printf '%s\n' "$string"
Text text hello!
text hello!
hello!
```

If your sed version doesn't support `\n` in the replacement then change it to either of these:

```
sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\'$'\n''/g' file

sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\
/g' file
```

If it doesn't support character classes then **get a new sed** but otherwise change `[[:punct:]]` to `[!?.]` and list all the punctuation chars inside the bracket expression or change it to `[^][ \ta-zA-Z0-9_-]` and list all the chars you do NOT want treated as punctuation inside the bracket expression.

Comment: yes yes, the first part looks good, but the adding into array should be done automaticly, since i may add more senteces into the file, so rather than putting them into the array manualy it would be better done trough some other script

Comment: so if possible i would like the output from $string=$(sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\n/g' file | grep 'hello!')
$ printf '%s\n' "$string"    to go into array (as said each line seperated in its own index (from the 3rd. part of the program you showed

Comment: Why populate the `string` at all though? If you want to read the file into an array then just do it as I show INSTEAD of reading it into a string, not in addition to. If you do want to populate a string first though then just do `readarray -t -d$'\n' array <<<"$string"`.

Comment: Oh, hang on - when you said `rather than putting them into the array manualy` did you think the `declare -a array` was me **assigning** values to the array? No, that's the output of me printing it with `declare -p`. The `readarray -t -d$'\n' array < <(sed 's/\([[:punct:]]\) /\1\n/g' file)` is the line that's populating the array from the file.